# Sitecore 10 JSS docker setup

Tags: jss, docker, sxa-jss

I am new to `Sitecore JSS` but have been doing development using `Sitecore` for 5 years.

I am trying to set up `JSS` on my `docker` image. I have been successfully able to update the docker file for `CM` & `CD` to install. The setup has worked successfully and below are some configurations in my docker file:

The following is my docker file on CD

```
# Add JSS module
COPY --from=jss C:\module\cd\content .\
COPY --from=jss C:\module\tools \module\tools
RUN C:\module\tools\Initialize-Content.ps1 -TargetPath .\; `
Remove-Item -Path C:\module -Recurse -Force;
```

The following is my docker file for CM:

```
# Add JSS module
COPY --from=jss \module\cm\content .\
COPY --from=jss \module\tools \module\tools
RUN C:\module\tools\Initialize-Content.ps1 -TargetPath .\; `
Remove-Item -Path C:\module -Recurse -Force;
# To install sitecore cli
RUN powershell -Command Start-Process c:/inetpub/node-v16.14.2-x64.msi -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
RUN npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
```

I have read some topics on how to build and start your first `JSS` application using `@jss-cli`. I am a little confused as to using `CLI` to create the app in docker. Because it requires access to the file system but I don't have access to the file system from my DEV machine. Should I create the tenant and everything from scratch and don't use `CLI` to build the application? or just use the source code from the sample project and deploy cms changes using unicorn?